# Spherical harmonic derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Consider the following substitution

```
Derivative[2, 0][S][th, ph] /. S -> Function[{th, ph}, SphericalHarmonicY[3, 0, th, ph]]
```

which gives correct answer. While for some cases, eg.

```
Derivative[2, 0][S][th, ph] /. S -> Function[{th, ph}, SphericalHarmonicY[3, 3, th, ph]]
```

will produce the

```
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0 24 \[Sqrt]70 E^(-I \[Phi]) ComplexInfinity)/(12 \[Sqrt]35) encountered. >>
```

error. Of course the command

```
D[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 3, th, ph], {th, 2}]
```

will produce the desired output. So the question is what is wrong with the substitution rule?

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the `Gamma` function generated by the direct derivation. Observe the result of  `Derivative[2, 0][SphericalHarmonicY[3, 3, #, #2] &]` and try `Limit[Derivative[2, 0][SphericalHarmonicY[3, 3, #, #2] &] /. Gamma[a_] -> Gamma[a + c], c -> 0][th, ph] // Simplify`. Not sure if it's a bug or just the property of `SphericalHarmonicY`.

Comment: This looks rather as a bug...